# How do I open ctrlp plugin file suggestions in Insert mode?

Tags: vim-plugin, ctrlp

I'm using [CtrlP](https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim) plugin to switch to other files in Vim by pressing `Ctrl-p`. But this only works in normal mode. I want to trigger it by pressing the same set of keys in insert mode as well. How can I do that? I couldn't find any mapping for insert mode in the help doc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried `inoremap <C-p> <Esc>:CtrlP<CR>` and it worked. Credit goes to @statox, who answered this question [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/21481/how-do-i-open-ctrlp-plugin-file-suggestions-in-insert-mode)